# use ggplot in R to draw line graph for multiple values against time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot several cities' housing prices against time using `ggplot` (line chart). 
I melted the data so that it looks like:

```
Dates         variable       value  
2010-01-01    Shanghai       20435  
2010-02-01    Shanghai       20782  
...           Shanghai       ...  
2018-07-01    Shanghai       22491  
2010-01-01    Hangzhou       18827  
...           Hangzhou       ...  
2018-07-01    Hangzhou       29255  
...           ...            ...
```

My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(scales)  
library(reshape2)  
Housingpriceslong <- melt(Housingprices, id=c("Dates"))  
ggplot(Housingpriceslong, aes(x=Dates, y=value, colour=Housingpriceslong$variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks = date_breaks("6 months"))
```

My questions are:

1. Something seems to be wrong and I don't get a proper graph, could you please help me correct my code?
2. The `scale_x_date` function does nothing either, my x-axis scale is still shown yearly.

Comment: Please read [how to make a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3283824) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your data/code. Use `dput` to provide representative & minimal sample data. Paste your code attempt as code text (use the editing tools to properly format code). And clearly articulate what you expect as output. *"Why is the graph so messed up like that"* is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

There are (potentially) two issues with your code:

1. You need to make sure that `Dates` represents a `Date` object: convert a `character` vector or `factor` with `as.Date` to a `Date` vector.
2. Don't use `$`-indexing inside `aes`: `colour=Housingpriceslong$variable` should be `colour = variable`).

The following works:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(Dates = as.Date(Dates)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Dates, value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(
        labels = scales::date_format("%Y-%m"),
        breaks = scales::date_breaks("6 months")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Dates         variable       value
2010-01-01    Shanghai       20435
2010-02-01    Shanghai       20782
2018-07-01    Shanghai       22491
2010-01-01    Hangzhou       18827
2018-07-01    Hangzhou       29255", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! The x-axis is working, but the graph still isn't.  
 Housingpriceslong <- melt(Housingprices, id=c("Dates"))
 Housingpriceslong %>%
  mutate(Dates = as.Date(Dates)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Dates, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(
  labels = scales::date_format("%Y-%m"),
  breaks = scales::date_breaks("6 months")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))